# Understanding animation with canvas

Tags: dart, flutter

**I'm a beginner with Dart and Flutter**

I'm trying to make a game which can help me to understand many features of these 2 languages.

I have a screen where I draw a circle and I want to translate it from the left to the right of the screen

```
class _GamePagePageState extends State<GamePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();
        leftToRightTranslation(100);
    }
    void leftToRightTranslation(int speed) {
        new Timer.periodic(new Duration(milliseconds: speed), (timer) {
            bulle.xPos++;
        });
     }
}

class MyPainter extends CustomPainter{
    Color lineColor;
    double width;
    double xPos = 50, yPos = 50;
    MyPainter({this.lineColor,this.width});
    @override
    void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
        Paint line = new Paint()
        ..color = lineColor
        ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
        ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
        ..strokeWidth = width;
        Offset offset = new Offset(xPos, yPos);
        double radius  = 1;
        canvas.drawCircle(
            offset,
            radius,
            line
         );
     }
     @override
     bool shouldRepaint(MyPainter oldDelegate) {
         return oldDelegate.xPos != xPos;
     }
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

The translation from left to right doesn't happen

I thought the `shouldRepaint` method have to update the bulle position whenever it changes.

When I perfom a hot reload, the bulle disappears, which mean the x position actually has changed and got bigger than the screen width

How to do the translation from the left to the right of the screen ?

Any other way to do it will be great appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50739048/flutter-i-am-looking-for-a-way-to-do-a-pulse-animation/50748925#50748925) for how to use an Animation with a custom Painter

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54286551/2252830